# Why does JSON.parse work on Google developer tools, but not in my js file?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been using the code below to get what I think is a JSON string from the openweathermap API.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=12&lon=-50&APPID=myKey');

request.send();

var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

The JSON string when I access it directly is this:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-50,"lat":12},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":301.461,"pressure":1025.84,"humidity":100,"temp_min":301.461,"temp_max":301.461,"sea_level":1025.82,"grnd_level":1025.84},"wind":{"speed":6.68,"deg":80.5004},"clouds":{"all":32},"dt":1507680994,"sys":{"message":0.0025,"sunrise":1507712963,"sunset":1507755824},"id":0,"name":"","cod":200}
```

However, when I used JSON.parse(request.responseText), I get a syntax error -- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse ()

But when I use parse on Chrome developer tools it works fine and I can access the values using their keys e.g. `JSON.parse(data)['coord']['lon']` returns -50

Comment: Did you log `request.responseText` before parsing to validate it is fetched ?

Comment: That is **not** how you read the response from an **async** operation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the asynchronous response before trying to get the response's contents. Could be achieved this way:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  }
};
```